# Iptables: How can I allow only one IP address to access a Centos 7 server?

Tags: iptables

I have 5 IP addresses for 5 different computers. All of them can access the server. I only want one of them to have access, how should I go about this with iptables?

Comment: You are looking at firewall functions. `iptables` is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your IP adrress is 192.168.1.1.

If so, add these rules on your server, in that order:

```
iptables -A input -s 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A output -d 192.168.1.1 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -P INPUT DROP  
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Keep in mind tha these are the simpliest way to allow only your IP to access this server.
You can also accept only connexions to certain ports or manage the states to prevent some applications to malfunction.
You may want to also add these rules before your DROP rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP  
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

But before meddling with iptables, be sure to ALWAYS log onto you server directly to avoid being cut out from it.
I hope I didn't make mistakes...